# Sluggishness with WebStorm and Meteor?

Tags: meteor, webstorm

So, I'm working on a Mac Mini, using WebStorm to fuss with Meteor apps.  I'm finding that WebStorm tends to get sluggish, and is constantly trying to index things.  I have 4 gigs of RAM, of which 791M seem to be allocated to WebStorm at any one time.  My disk drive is 500GB, and I make sure there's always at least 20% to 30% free space.

So, a few questions...  is it Meteor's bundle process that's causing WebStorm to do the indexing?  Is there any way to optimize the indexing?  Make it run less frequently?  Ignore the .meteor directory, perhaps?  Is 20% of available RAM an appropriate amount to allocate to WebStorm for Meteor development?  Are there any other things that people can recommend to optimize WebStorm so it's not so sluggish?

Thanks in advance for any recommendations!

Comment: Have you [searched the official Webstorm support site](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/search.jspa;jsessionid=550D37F46AF153C8C3490BD058EA94BE?q=indexing&resultTypes=DOCUMENT&resultTypes=MESSAGE&resultTypes=COMMENT&dateRange=all&communityID=9778&username=)? Not sure if SO is the  right place to ask for support for your IDE...

Comment: See http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1253.

Comment: I wasn't even aware the devnet.jetbrains.com site existed!  It makes total sense that it does; just, somehow, it wasn't on my radar or showing up in my searches.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!!

Comment: And.... duh, the 'Directories' tab in preferences is where you exclude directories.  For some reason, I was thinking that tab was for defining libraries locations and includes, not excludes.  Totally wasn't thinking along those lines; but thanks to devnet.jetbrains.com, found the info I needed!  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Martin said - exclude the directories where Meteor stores it compiled files: `.meteor\local` and `.meteor\meteorite` (when using meteorite).

To have Meteor suggestions / ... add the Meteor source as an external library: `/usr/lib/meteor/packages/`. I'm using PhpStorm as well and add the path to the PHP include path (doesn't matter it's not a PHP-library).

When adding it as a JavaScript Library in the project settings the directory structure gets lost and you have to repeat this when upgrading meteor.

Comment: Perfect!  That seems to have done the trick.  And thanks for cluing me into the Meteor suggestions feature!  Looking forward to trying that out.

Comment: Just perfect! However, on my Mac I found that meteor/packages is located at /usr/local/meteor/packages. Don't know for sure but guess that's the standard Mac location for Meteor...

Comment: WebStorm doesn't yet support Meteor specifically, so it considers Meteor apps as Node.js apps, without any special treatment. You should [vote for WebStorm to add Meteor support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264)!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using PHPStoem for my meteor development and I am having the same issue as you do. I guess the engine in PHPStorm is identical to WebStorm...

I'm unsure if increasing the amount of RAM available to the IDE actually will have any effect. The issue is related to the IDE re-indexing the folder-tree whenever changes are made to any file(s) in the tree.
When meteor is running and changes is made to a file, meteor is bundling the whole application into the .meteor folder why the tree is re-indexed.

I haven't tried it out yet, but I guess what actually will help is to add the .meteor-folder to the ignore list so it wont be re-indexed every time a file-change happens.

Comment: Da'ha!  Try Settings > Directories > Exclude to prevent indexing of the .meteor directory.  That seems to have done the trick.

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5279592#5279592

Comment: WebStorm doesn't yet support Meteor specifically, so it considers Meteor apps as Node.js apps, without any special treatment like excluding certain directories. Help fix that by [voting for WebStorm to add Meteor support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264)!